# Which DB design is faster: a unique index and INSERT IGNORE, or using SELECT to find existing records?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with just one column: userid.

When a user accesses a certain page, his userid is being inserted to the table. Userids are unique, so there shouldn't be two of the same userids in that table.

I'm considering two designs:

1. Making the column unique and using `INSERT` commands every time a user accesses that page.
2. Checking if the user is already recorded in the table by `SELECT`ing from the table, then `INSERT`ing if no record is found.

Which one is faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely create a `UNIQUE` index, or, better, make this column a `PRIMARY KEY`.

You need an index to make your checks fast anyway.

Why don't make this index `UNIQUE` so that you have another fallback option (if you for some reason forgot to check with `SELECT`)?

If your table is `InnoDB`, it will have a `PRIMARY KEY` anyway, since all `InnoDB` tables are index-organized by design.

In case you didn't declare a `PRIMARY KEY` in your table, `InnoDB` will create a *hidden* column to be a primary key, thus making your table twise as large and you will not have an index on your column.

Creating a `PRIMARY KEY` on your column is a win-win.

You can issue

```
INSERT
IGNORE
INTO    mytable
VALUES  (userid)
```

and check how many records were affected.

If `0`, there was a key violation, but no exception.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)?

If a user already exists it's being replaced, if it doesn't a new row is inserted.

Comment: replace is quite slow for bigger tables.

Comment: `REPLACE` is outdated. It's an equivalent of a `DELETE` followed by `INSERT`. `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (or `INSERT IGNORE` in this very case of one column) is much more efficient.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Do you have a source for that? I'm pretty sure it's still faster than 2 queries though.

Comment: `@André Hoffmann`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html

`INSERT IGNORE` is one query.

Comment: Actually my question was pointed at dusoft. I haven't seen your comment when I wrote this. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

what about doing update, e.g.

```
UPDATE xxx SET x=x+1 WHERE userid=y
```

and if that fails (e.g. no matched rows), then do an insert for a new user?

Comment: may be. i can add a new column like last_login, and update that.

Comment: i think that's better, even for future design

Answer (score 1):

SELECT is faster... but you'd prefer SELECT check not because of this, but to escape from rasing an error..

Answer (score 0):

orrrrrrr

```
INSERT INTO xxx (`userid`) VALUES (4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userid=VALUE(`userid`)
```

Comment: this is a little irrelevant for just one field but if you expanded the table you can update say the last seen date etc etc

Comment: Since there's really nothing to update, it's a little bit overkill for the specific example listed.  That said, in a general sense this is probably the one to use for most 'real-life' scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it unique in any cases.

Wether to check first using SELECT, depends on what scenario is most common. If you have new users all the time, and only occationally existing users, it might be overall faster for the system to just insert and catch the exception in the rare occations this happens, but exception is slower than check first and then insert, so if it is a common scenario that it is an existing user, you should allways check first with select.