# How to skip duplicates using INSERT INTO in a better optimized way?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to build as an experiment a sort of dictionary where any user can suggest new words.

In order to avoid duplicates, I used to do a query `SELECT` that search for that word and if size is zero then I do the `INSERT INTO`.

I feel this method works well only if you need to warn the user br lese, but in my case I want something faster and automated and silent.

The very first entry of the word (the very first time a user suggests that word) is going to be the ID of the page word so I don't want to use `REPLACE`.

I was wondering whether using `INSERT IGNORE` can be the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which DB design is faster: a unique index and INSERT IGNORE, or using SELECT to find existing records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328074/which-db-design-is-faster-a-unique-index-and-insert-ignore-or-using-select-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT IGNORE will do the trick for you here.  You just need to make sure you have a UNIQUE index defined on the column you don't want duplicated.

Another options is INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE which won't insert the value again, but will allow you update other columns in that row.  A counter or timestamp for example.

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT INTO" to ignore later duplicates, or "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to take new fields from the later duplicates: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html