# More Time Consuming/CPU Extensive INSERT IGNORE or Select Count(*)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working with a program where I have to check hundreds of variables to see if they are already in the database.  It usually takes a while to run.  I'm using INSERT IGNORE for all the variables.  Should I change this to check if they exist in the database first?  Which function adds more wait to to the end user?

In this program, most of the inserts will be duplicates.  So this situation will come up pretty often.

Maybe it would make the most sense to get rid of duplicates before attempting to insert?  (I'm working with PHP IMAP library & emails)

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to make the columns `UNIQUE` and let the database do the work of figuring out if it should be added.

Comment: @D.N.: since he said that he is already using `INSERT IGNORE` I bet he already has specified that field(s) as unique ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which DB design is faster: a unique index and INSERT IGNORE, or using SELECT to find existing records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328074/which-db-design-is-faster-a-unique-index-and-insert-ignore-or-using-select-to)

Answer (score 0):

First of all definitely don't do a SELECT and then INSERT, that's completely pointless. Instead, think about the below;

- What kind of settings are these? Should they really belong in the database or in a PHP config file?
- Investigate into `LOAD DATA INTO` which uses IGNORE on duplicate key by default.
- Is it really nessasary to check all the time? Surely this will be only done upon installation/setup?

Comment: it's email messages, not settings. Ever used some webmail service?

Comment: This happens for each of our users - hundreds of times a day.